# Unit Tests and IoC Autofac - Should We Use Mocks or IoC in Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq, autofac, ioc-container

I use Autofac IoC in my app but I am trying to write some unit tests and in order to instantiate some of my view models, I need to provide some dependencies to them.

For example, my `Car` class has dependency on some `ISession` object which could be our own implementation or a 3rd party:

```
public class Car
{
  public Car(ISession session) {...}
}
```

In real code, Autofac takes care for this by registering `ISession` and `Car` with Autofac container and then resolving it.  That is all fine.

But for unit tests, it feels wrong to me to use Autofac and register and resolve these like in app code.

My understanding of unit tests is that:

1. I think that unite tests should do this by using mocks instead of using IoC.  So, instead of registering and resolving ISession and Car, ISession should be mocked and passed to Car subject under test (sut) object.
2. Unit tests should not use IoC such as Autofac or any other at all but rather mock dependencies.  This is to isolate unit tests.  If we use IoC, we would be doing integration test, not a unit test.
3. Unit tests should be written by developer, integration tests should be written by testers/qa

Is this correct?

Comment: The answers here will likely end up with opinions rather than an actual concrete "correct response" - some people like to use DI to wire up complex unit tests, some think if you need DI then it indicates the test is too complex and indicates you need to refactor.

Comment: https://github.com/moq/Moq.AutoMocker

Comment: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/moq.html